Google Looker Studio - how to make a time series stacked column chart?
My chart doesn't show all the data from the BigQuery view that was connected to the report.
Here is an example:

I ask to show me the sum of clicks by date for the last 30 days (Apr 7 to May 6). But it shows data up to Apr 16.
enter image description here

Then I ask to see the data for the last 7 days (Apr 30 - May 6). I can now see the most recent data. So, it exists.enter image description here

If I delete Data Range controller, it shows the data up to Apr 4.
enter image description here


What do I need to do to see all the data available?
I tried to play with date format, but I found out that the same date format works for some charts not causing this issue and doesn't work in this case from the example.
This is how I prepare dates in my big query views:
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS Date

UPDATE. If I make a time series line chart then everything is fine. The problem occurs in the case of a column bar chart.
NEW PROBLEM. How can I make a time series stacked column chart?
